# A neutral word for “ecclesiasticism”

Tags: single-word-requests

The common definition given for the word “ecclesiasticism” is:

> adherence or over-attention to details of Church practice

Take the following observation (slightly paraphrased from the original article):

> When ecclesiasticism attempts to address the physical realm, it frequently fails.

With respect to above usage (that theism should not interfere with physical studies, etc.), does the word “ecclesiasticism” always carry connection with Christianity and the Church? Is there a word where I want to make the same point, but without emphasizing any specific religion?

Comment: When supernatural philosophies attempts to address the secular, they frequently fail. *These insights, in turn, may help us understand how secular, naturalistic philosophies of life (in contrast to supernatural philosophies like traditional religions) could become more popular* https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/darwin-eternity/201512/star-wars-christmas-and-constraints-secular-influence?collection=1083035

Comment: Why not just say “religion”?

Comment: Ecclesiasticism is a subset of religion which is a subset of "supernatural philosophy". Neither is  a synonym for it.

Comment: I get the impression that some religions (Judaism and Islam for instance) don't have a word for 'ecclesiasticism' because the practice of those religions is highly prescribed anyway. Whether Hinduism, Buddhism, Sikkism and so on have similar concepts I don't know. I suspect they might.

Answer (score 1):

*Ecclesia* and its derivatives does always carry a connection with the Church, and has done since the word was used in the Gospels and the writings of St Paul.

> κἀγὼ δέ σοι λέγω ὅτι σὺ εἶ Πέτρος, καὶ ἐπὶ ταύτῃ τῇ πέτρᾳ οἰκοδομήσω μου τὴν ἐκκλησίαν, καὶ πύλαι ἅδου οὐ κατισχύσουσιν αὐτῆς.
>
> I also say to you that you are Peter, and upon this rock I will build my Church; and the gates of Hades will not overpower it. (Mt 16:18 NASB)

> τῇ ἐκκλησίᾳ τοῦ θεοῦ τῇ οὔσῃ ἐν Κορίνθῳ, ἡγιασμένοις ἐν Χριστῷ Ἰησοῦ, κλητοῖς ἁγίοις, σὺν πᾶσιν τοῖς ἐπικαλουμένοις τὸ ὄνομα τοῦ κυρίου ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ ἐν παντὶ τόπῳ, αὐτῶν καὶ ἡμῶν:
>
> To the church of God which is at Corinth, to those who have been sanctified in Christ Jesus, saints by calling, with all who in every place call on the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, their Lord and ours: (1 Cor 1:2 NASB)

To my knowledge the word has not been claimed by or applied to other religions.

A suitable alternative might be ***religiosity,*** or your own ***theism.***

> religiosity: Strong religious feeling or belief. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/religiosity))
>
> theism: Belief in the existence of a god or gods, specifically of a creator who intervenes in the universe. ([ibid](https://www.lexico.com/definition/theism).)

Lexico points out that *theism* differs from ***deism:***

> deism: Belief in the existence of a supreme being, specifically of a creator who does not intervene in the universe. ([ibid](https://www.lexico.com/definition/deism).)

---

[It's a pity that certain implementations — maybe all implementations — of Georgia don't contain all accented Greek characters. What appears as ὼ for example should look like `ὼ`.]

Comment: An interesting diversion into the origin and overtones of the questioner's stated view of the word but it does not answer the question. Words like theism, deism & religiosity apply at high level and do not capture the connotations of lower level (almost administrative) practices and procedures of religion (Christian ecclesiasticism, or the questioner's sought-for equivalent) rather than of religious belief. Your final orthographic comment persuades me that you have been commendably carried away by over-enthusiasm for didactic explanation.

Comment: Naturally, I disagree. The OP has two questions, and I think both are answered.

Comment: Naturally. And "interesting" was not a euphemism; it was indeed interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Ecclesiasticism is a particular branch of Christianity that lays emphasis on organised church practice. Not all Christians are practitioners of Ecclesiasticism. Not even all Christian organisations practice Ecclesiasticism.

The word derives from the Greek for church, meaning a religious congregation or community rather than a building. As such it will be assumed to refer to Christianity.

If you want to expand the word to include other religions you will have to find the names of equivalent groups within those religions, or else make it deliberately inclusive. Such as saying "Ecclesiasticism and its equivalent in other religions".